# How to control the projection definition in MongoDb using C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core-3.1, projection, .net-core-3.1

I have a domain class like this.

```
public class Thing
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> Stuff { get; set; }
}
```

I'm retrieving it from my DB using the following.

```
return await _db.Things
    .Find(x => x.Name == name)
    .SingleOrDefaultAsync(token);
```

As I noticed, there might be huge chunks of unnecessary data so I used a projection like this.

```
ProjectionDefinition<Thing> projection = Builders<Thing>
    .Projection
    .Include(a => a.Id)
    .Include(a => a.Name);

BsonDocument projected = await _dbContext.Things
    .Find(x => x.Name == name)
    .Project(projection)
    .SingleOrDefaultAsync(token);
```

This works but, naturally, cuts of **all** the dictionary contents. I'd like to alter the definition of projection to include the field but perform a filtration of the constituting elements. Suppose I'd only want to bring in the keys of said dictionary that start with *duck*. An attempt  might be something like this.

```
ProjectionDefinition<Thing> projection = Builders<Thing>
    .Projection
    .Include(a => a.Id)
    .Include(a => a.Name)
    .Include(a => a.Stuff.Where(b => b.Key.StartsWith("duck")));
```

That resulted in exception as follows.

> System.NotSupportedException: The expression tree is not supported: {document}{configuration}

Given my ignorance with MongoDb, I have no idea if I should add something, remove something or forget the idea all together. I also tried to work with the original type to be able to filter the stuff that way but the only solution I've got was post-fetch, basically trumming the retrieved data. I'd like to lower the payload from the DB to my service.

```
Thing projected = await _dbContext.Things
    .Find(x => x.Name == name)
    .Project<Thing>(projection)
    .SingleOrDefaultAsync(token);
```

Is it doable at all and if so, how (or at least what to google for)?

Proof of effort: [code examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46990426/1525840), [general operations](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/quick-start-c-and-mongodb--read-operations), [tutorials](https://www.codementor.io/@damithg/mongodb-c-tutorial-the-easy-way-v8t5e6v51), [wrong answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64063667/conditional-projection-in-mongodb-using-c-sharp-driver) etc. It might be out there somewhere but I failed to find it (or recognize if found).

Finally, I landed into the following - God forgive me for I know not what I'm doing. Is this at all in the right direction or is a gang of crazy donkeys going to bite me in the lower back for this?!

```
ProjectionDefinition<Thing, Thing> wtf = Builders<Thing>.Projection
    .Expression(a => new Thing
    {
        Id = a.Id,
        Name = a.Name,
        Stuff = a.Stuff
            .Where(b => b.Key == scope)
            .ToDictionary(b => scope, b => b.Value)
    });
```

Comment: This seems a bit tricky and I don't have much idea but `.NET` things. But I found something for you that might help you - https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.7/reference/driver/definitions/#find

Comment: Also see this question about the error you are getting - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55597781/expression-tree-is-not-supported-on-updateoneasync

Comment: Please post a sample document with the `stuff` field and what you want in your projected stuff.

Comment: @prasad_ Not sure what you're requesting. A sample document? The class describing it is shown in the first sample at the top. The field `Stuff` is a dictionary of string as a key and string as a value. I want to be able to retrieve the document but only pull a single element of the dictionary part, instead of all of them. Please elaborate if I missed something.

Comment: Generally, the issue of filtering a dictionary (in MongoDB its an object or embedded document) based upon the key name is solved using an aggregate query. You can convert the dictionary's key-value pairs to an array (using the aggregate operator `$objectToArray`) and filter(in your case can use a regex) the array by the key name .

Comment: @prasad_ Would you post a short code sample showing what you mean? I got the intended message of yours but can't see precisely how it relates to the specific issue at hand. Perhaps it's easier if we can formalize it (i.e. show some code doing what you referred to)?

Comment: I have posted an answer as per my earlier comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a `mongo` shell query with MongoDB v4.2.8.

Consider this input document:

```
{
        "_id" : 1,
        "name" : "john",
        "stuff" : {
                "mycolor" : "red",
                "fruit" : "apple",
                "mybook" : "programming gems",
                "movie" : "star wars"
        }
}
```

The goal is to *project* the `name` and `stuff` fields, but `stuff` with only field names starting with `"my"`.

The aggregation query:

```
db.test.aggregate([
  { 
      $project: { 
          _id: 0, 
          name: 1, 
          stuff: { 
              $filter: { 
                  input: { $objectToArray: "$stuff" }, 
                  as: "stf", 
                  cond: { $regexMatch: { input: "$$stf.k" , regex: "^my" } }
              }
          }
      }
  },
  { 
      $addFields: { stuff: { $arrayToObject: "$stuff" } } 
  }
])
```

And, the projected output:

```
{
        "name" : "john",
        "stuff" : {
                "mycolor" : "red",
                "mybook" : "programming gems"
        }
}
```

Comment: What is the input to the regex (i.e. *$$stf.k*)? I'm guessing that it relates to the filter output somehow but it's not apparent to be. Also, the *.k* tells me nothing in the context. Am I missing the point  or is it some special mango-script syntax?

Comment: The result of `{ $objectToArray: "$stuff" }` (see [$objectToArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/)); its an array. E.g., each array element is like `{"k" : "mycolor", "v" : "red"}` and corresponds to key-value `"mycolor" : "red"`. Next, iterate the array, using `$filter` and match with the regex. In the following `$addFields`, convert that filtered array back into key-value dictionary. `"stf"` represents each array element used in the $filter.

Comment: Got it, now. Based on the trickyness of the solution, I'll change my dictionary to an array. It's not my decision but I'm going to press my dev-lead to make the decision to accept array instead by threatening them to do it themselves otherwise. I'm assuming that you have little to contribute with when it comes to actual C# syntax in the Mongo driver. If I'm wrong on this point, feel free to shoot in some .NET'y code. Otherwise, thanks for the stuff anyway. It was big help.

Comment: Remind me in a day or two so I don't forget to award you the bounty. Important for the credit to go when the credit is due.

Comment: _"Based on the trickyness of the solution, I'll change my dictionary to an array."_ I think its good design decision. Also see this: [MongoDB Blog Post - Attribute Pattern](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/building-with-patterns-the-attribute-pattern). It may also allow you to create indexes for an efficient search (indexes on array fields are called as Multikey Index).